# conexión SQL Server con XAMPP

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

Estoy tratando de conectar mi servidor XAMPP a SQL Server en local (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) para usarlo con una pagina web php. He descargado los drivers para usar php y los archivos .dll los he puesto en la carpeta php dentro de XAMPP. Hasta aquí creo que todo está correcto. Para hacer una prueba de conexión abro desde localhost un archivo llamado conexion.php con el siguiente código:

```
<?php
/* Nombre del servidor. */
$serverName = "(local)";
/* Usuario y clave.  */
$uid = "";
$pwd = "";
/* Array asociativo con la información de la conexion */
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
"PWD"=>$pwd,
"Database"=>"test");

/* Nos conectamos mediante la autenticación de SQL Server . */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
echo "No es posible conectarse al servidor.</br>";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* Query que nos mostrara el usuario con el que nos hemos conectado a la base de datos. */
$tsql = "SELECT CONVERT(varchar(32), SUSER_SNAME())";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if( $stmt === false )
{
echo "Error al ejecutar consulta.</br>";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
/* Mostramos el resultado. */
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
echo "User login: ".$row[0]."</br>";
/* Cerramos la conexión, muy importante. */
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
```

El caso es que he instalado SSMS y lo único que he hecho ha sido crear una nueva base de datos llamada 'test'. Nada más; no he creado ni usuarios ni contraseñas. Entonces las variables `$uid`y `$pwd`las he dejado vacías, de todos modos tampoco sabría qué poner.
El error que me genera al ejecutar la página es este:

```
No es posible conectarse al servidor.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error de inicio de sesi�n del usuario 'DESKTOP-FHALK16\Marcos'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error de inicio de sesi�n del usuario 'DESKTOP-FHALK16\Marcos'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]No se puede abrir la base de datos "test" solicitada por el inicio de sesi�n. Error de inicio de sesi�n. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]No se puede abrir la base de datos "test" solicitada por el inicio de sesi�n. Error de inicio de sesi�n. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error de inicio de sesi�n del usuario 'DESKTOP-FHALK16\Marcos'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error de inicio de sesi�n del usuario 'DESKTOP-FHALK16\Marcos'. ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]No se puede abrir la base de datos "test" solicitada por el inicio de sesi�n. Error de inicio de sesi�n. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]No se puede abrir la base de datos "test" solicitada por el inicio de sesi�n. Error de inicio de sesi�n. ) )
```

Comment: prueba con phpinfo() a ver que error te tira con mssql

Comment: he incluido la función `phpinfo()` en el código para que la ejecute cuando no se pueda conectar, pero en qué parte puedo ver el error? perdón por mi ignorancia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el error, pareciera que PHP se estaría intentando conectarse con el usuario de red o local `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error de inicio de sesi�n del usuario 'DESKTOP-FHALK16\Marcos'`, por lo que podemos descartar problemas de drivers y otros, al menos la comunicación inicial con el MSSQL se logra. Al usar el usuario de red, si la  instancia de SQL Server no tiene configurada la seguridad integrada, jamás vas a poder conectarte. Por lo que tienes dos opciones:

1. Habilitar la seguridad integrada en el MSSQL
2. Crear usuario/contraseña para la BD en MSSQL y conectarse mediante los mismos

Answer (score -1):

En principio haz la conexión desde el SSMS a la BD, luego pon el usuario y password usaste en tu script.

Funciona?

Crea el usuario y el password, con los permisos a la BD o simplemente habilita el sa.

Saludos

Comment: el caso es que nada más instalar el SSMS he creado una base de datos, no he creado ni usuarios ni nada más, por lo tanto en el script las variables de usuario y contraseña están vacías

Comment: actualice la respuesta, saludos